# How to do this query in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables `Product`, `Supplier`, and `Secondary_Supplier`. They look like this:

I need to make this query:

Which are the name of the suppliers that supplied most (different) categories?" Note: can be more than one. Also every product as a principal supplier and at least one secondary supplier.

```
Supplier

|ID | name|
----------
|1  | John|
----------
|2  | Andrew|
----------
|3  | Mariah|
----------
|4  | Drew|
----------
```

Secondary Supplier

```
|ID | ProdID|
----------
|4  | 121 |
----------
|1  | 122 |
----------
|2  | 123 |
----------
|2  | 125 |
----------
|3  | 124 |
----------
```

Product

```
|ProdID | Prim_ID | Category |       
----------------------------
|121    | 2        | Tampons|
----------------------------
|122    | 3        | Soda|
----------------------------
|123    | 3        | Makeup|
----------------------------
|124    | 4        | Chicken|
----------------------------
|125    | 1        | Tampons|
----------------------------
```

After I run the query, it should give me something like this:

```
|name  | COUNT|
-------------
|Mariah| 3|
-------------
```

The problem is that a product has a primary supplier and at least one secondary supplier. So when I do product natural join `Secondary_Supplier` my new table has 2 rows with Suppliers ID´s and I need to search in both rows.

I Tried this:

```sql
Select COUNT(DISTINCT category) as count, Prim_ID
From Product
Group by Prim_ID
Order by count DESC
Limit 1;
```

But I only get the primary supplier (`Prim_ID`). Also if I have one or more it only shows one of them (I think it's because of `limit 1`)

Answer (score 0):

If you qre looking for for all the Prim_id with count = max count

You can select joining the max value of count eg:

```
Select COUNT(DISTINCT category) as count, Prim_ID
From Product
FULL JOIN (
  Select COUNT(DISTINCT category) as count, Prim_ID
  From Product
  Group by Prim_ID
  Order by count DESC
  Limit 1
) t 
Group by Prim_ID
having count = t.count
```